# Vue.js reactivity of complex objects in a store

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

**My Problem**

I am trying to store a list of complex items in a store and access these items from a component. I have a mqtt interface which receives data for these items and updates their values in the store. However, the ui does not react to updating the properties of these items.

**Structure**

In my store, i have two mutations:

```js
state: {
  itemList:{}
},
mutations: {
  /// adds a new item to itemList
  [ADD_ITEM](state, item) {
    if (item&& !state.itemList[item.itemId])
    {
      Vue.set(state.itemList, item.itemId, item);
    }
  },
  /// updates an existing item with data from payload
  [SET_ITEM_STAT](state, { itemId, payload }) {
    var item= state.itemList[itemId];
    if (item) {
      item.prop1 = payload.prop1;
      item.prop2 = payload.prop2;
    } 
  }
},
actions: {
  /// is called from outside once when connection to mqtt (re-)established
  initializeMqttSubscriptions({ commit, dispatch }, mqtt){
    mqtt.subscribeItem("items/stat", async function(itemId, topic, payload) {
      commit(SET_ITEM_STAT, { itemId, payload });
    });
  },
  ...
}
```

I also tried:

- setting the item properties using `Vue.set(state.itemList, itemId, item);`
- setting the item properties using `Vue.set(state.itemList[itemId], 'prop1', payload.prop1);`

I also want to show how i built the Component which accesses and displays these items (`Item.vue`). It is one component, that gets passed the `itemId` to show via the route params. I've got the following computed properties:

```html
<template>
<div class="grid-page">
    <h1 class="page-title">Item- <span class="fw-semi-bold">{{ id }}</span></h1>
    <div>
        <Widget v-if="item">
            {{ item.prop1 }}
...
```

```js
...
computed: {
  id(){
    return this.$route.params.itemId;
  },
  item(){
    return this.$store.state.items.itemList[this.id];
  }
}
```

So when the route parameter `itemId`changes, i successfully can see the item data, everything is fine. But if i update the properties of an item with the mutation shown above, no update in view is triggered.

I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint what i am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i can't comment to ask for some clarifications,

If you're itemlist is an nested object, try out with Object.assign

```
[SET_ITEM_STAT](state, { itemId, payload }) {
    var item= state.itemList[itemId];
    if (item) {
this.state.itemList[itemId] = Object.assign({}, this.state.itemList[itemId].prop1, {payload.prop1})
this.state.itemList[itemId] = Object.assign({}, this.state.itemList[itemId].prop2, {payload.prop2})

// or
this.state.itemList[itemId] = Object.assign({}, this.state.itemList[itemId], {prop1: payload.prop1, prop2: payload.prop2})
    } 
  }
```

Let me know how it goes

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: Thanks Dario, that solved my problem! I had tried creating a new instance using the spread syntax, but i understand now, that this did not really create a deep copy of the item.

Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure to help :)